# Why is this shift operation evaluating to true in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I recently came across [this question and it's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25994001/how-to-calculate-byte-length-containing-utf8-characters-using-javascript) while trying to create my own UI for code golfing. It's goal is to count the number of bytes in a given UTF-8 string:

```
function countUtf8Bytes(s) {
    var b = 0, i = 0, c
    for(;c=s.charCodeAt(i++);b+=c>>11?3:c>>7?2:1);
    return b
}
```

Now, I primarily work with C# but I'm aware that JavaScript contains additional logical operators such as strict equality (`===`), but I had never seen anything use what looked like a left or right shift (`<<` and `>>` respectively). However, as I broke down this snippet, I couldn't help but notice the dual usage of the ternary operator (`?:`):

```
b += c >> 11 ? 3 : c >> 7 ? 2 : 1
```

I *assumed* this should be read as a *strict* evaluation, similar to strict equality. However, upon searching for the operator online with relation to JavaScript, I'm finding no evidence of this. In-fact, a few posts explicitly mention that no such operator exists ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14533046/why-doesnt-javascript-have-strict-greater-less-than-comparison-operators), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143520/javascript-equality-triple-equals-but-what-about-greater-than-and-less-than) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163256/greater-than-and-lower-than-or-equal-strict-forms) are a few here on StackOverflow).

After learning that no such operator exists in JavaScript, I attempted to break it down and test it out. This resulted in me heading over to [Playcode.io](https://playcode.io/new/) with the following snippet:

```js
var c = ''.charCodeAt(0);
console.log(c)
console.log(c >> 11)
if (c >> 11)
    console.log('3')
else {
  if (c >> 7)
      console.log('2')
  else
      console.log('1')
}
```

Running this snippet will produce the output:

```
55357
27
3
```

So now I'm really confused. Why is `27` evaluating as true? I continued testing and swapped  for `a`. Now the output is:

```
97
0
1
```

I'd understand this result, if it weren't for the fact that step two above prints `27`.

---

Why is this right shift being utilized as a logical evaluation, and what am I missing here?

Comment: Any nonzero number evaluates to true, zero evaluates to false. The shift operator has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Javascript works similar to C/C++ where `0` is false and anything not zero is true. So `1` is true and `27` is true and `-101` is true. In addition javascript also considers other things to be true. A non-empty string is true so `"hello"` is true but `""` is false. An object is true, an array is true etc. Values considered false are `false`, `0`, `undefined`, `null`, the empty string and `NaN` (note that the empty array is true)